# Bitbucket User not listed in the Project permissions & Repository permissions but able to push code

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

User not listed when I check on repository level permission as well as project level permission but User able to push code on repository. I am able to see Push log user merge request and audit log.
where I have to check now?

I am able to see Push log user merge request and audit log.

Comment: Maybe the permissions are just unrestricted? Is the permission/access control enabled and then specified correctly?

Comment: Push via https? Via ssh? Can the user see and edit the repository in the web UI? Is an ssh access key or an http token that does not belong to the user being used to git push?